# C - How to read with sscanf <int><string><int>?

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc, scanf

I have a file with `<int><string><int>` and I save it into a buffer and read it afterwards using a pipe. The string is alphanumeric.

```
FILE *est = fopen ("file.txt","r");
fgets( buffer1, 256, est);
write(fd[i][1], buffer1, BUFFERSIZE);

.
.
.

int r = read(fd[i][0], buffer1, BUFFERSIZE);
sscanf(buffer1,"<%d><%s><%d>", &a, b, &c);
```

The problem is when I read the string it "eats" the `><%d>` and it interprets everything as a string. For example if I had `<10><5jj8j><10>` the variables would be `a=10`, `b= "5jj8j"><10>` and `c` to whatever it is initialized.

How can I use `sscanf` to read the string between `<>` right?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Another advice is to employ `fscanf` instad of `sscanf` as you already have a file opened. You may want to `fdopen` it to retrieve `FILE` pointer and use `fscanf` to read. Or use a `getline`  first to read a whole line and then call to `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `"%s"` saves all non-white-space characters and OP does not want `'>'` to be saved as part of the string, use `"%[]"`.

Use `"%n"` to detect if scan completed as `n`, being at the end, will only change if *all* the format matched.

```
// sscanf(buffer1,"<%d><%s><%d>", &a, b, &c);
int n = 0;
char b[100];
sscanf(buffer1,"<%d><%99[^>]><%d>%n", &a, b, &c, &n);
if (n > 0) {
  ; // Scan completed - success;
} else {
  ; // Scan failed
}
```